# Invoke terminal Script on google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

For about 5 hours now i have been trying to deploy a website on my local network, I am using google app engine and will run it locally. What im trying to do is invoke a terminal script once the user clicks the "Submit" button on my page.

The script will run on my server (), Well, the script runs fine, but Google app engine is giving an error everytime i try to invoke it...

I am using ubuntu 12.04, Python for programming in GAE.... and the error occurs on this line...

```
subprocess.call(['sendSMS.sh %s %s' % (s1,s2)])
```

and the error says:

> subprocess.call(['sendSMS.sh %s %s' % (s1,s2)]) AttributeError:
>   'module' object has no attribute 'call'

Comment: You haven't by chance called your file `subprocess.py` have you? That is one possible source of such an error.

Comment: Also as far as I know you cannot run a bash script on App Engine since you are not allowed to access the filesystem.

Comment: i see... that a bummer, well i think i might have to go with LAMP then...?

Comment: you could still use python. perhaps on amazon ec2.

Comment: What does the script do? Perhaps it can be implemented in Python?

Comment: Why would you deploy a GAE application locally? The whole point of using GAE is the scalability offered by running on Google's architecture - the tradeoff is restrictions like this. If you're running a local server, use something like Django.

Comment: I used GAE because that is what my limited knowledge could come up with, I know you are right in saying why i would deploy gae locally... and thanks for the Django, ill definitely check it out!

Comment: oh and my script actually invokes some commands for gammu to send messages over the cellular network using the phone i have attached to the server....

Comment: Right, I would just add that "Django" isn't really a replacement for "App Engine". Django is a web framework that runs on any web server (including App Engine), whereas App Engine is at the server level. You will need a web server like Apache. Then you can run Django on it, or just use a simple WSGI app like a `webapp2` app. (The choice to use Django is orthogonal to the choice to use App Engine.) See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `subprocess.call` on Google App Engine. App Engine has no file system (as @bernie explained in the comments) and you cannot run arbitrary code on the Google infrastructure -- only Python (and Java and Go) code.

It looks like you were never planning to upload your app to run on the Google platform (since then you couldn't use the phone you have attached to your own server), and that implies you were planning to use the development server in production. This is a **very bad idea** -- the development server is meant for testing your app before uploading it to the Google platform, and should never be used in production.

Since you have your own server, you should be running a production web server such as Apache. If you have used `webapp2` (as recommended by the App Engine tutorial), you can still make use of your existing code. Just use Apache's [mod_wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/) and then deploy your `webapp2` app in Apache on your server.

Comment: I see... so i should go for a LAMP system and then use mod_wsgi to deploy my existing app... am i right?

Comment: Yep, sounds good. If you have already written App-Engine-specific code, you may need to modify it (i.e., if you are using App Engine services such as datastore, they obviously won't work on a regular LAMP stack). But `webapp2` should still work fine -- no need for Django unless you are looking for a more powerful web framework.